# need help uploading file in background

Tags: nsurlconnection

I am uploading video file to server. Everything working fine if app in foreground. If while uploading app goes to background and come back then file uploading stops and show time out error.

I have try to use performinbackground. But nothing changes.

Please help.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about what you're doing before we can help you. Please post some code that's not working in the background. Also, is this MacOS or iOS?

Comment: Please provide code that you have tried. Please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add this code in your appdelegte ,then your app  will run a few minutes in background.

```
    @interface AppDelegate ()
    {
        UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier _bgTaskIdentifier;
    }

    -(void)beginBackgroundTask:(UIApplication*)app;

    -(void)endBackgroundTask:(UIApplication*)app;

    @end


    -(void)beginBackgroundTask:(UIApplication*)app
    {
        _bgTaskIdentifier = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            [self endBackgroundTask:app];
        }];
    }

    -(void)endBackgroundTask:(UIApplication*)app
    {
        if (_bgTaskIdentifier != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
            [app endBackgroundTask:_bgTaskIdentifier];
            _bgTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }
    }
```